# Getting Error When Trying to Call Function from Another Header File (C++)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, header-files

I have developed a dual-parameter binary search tree, and am now trying to apply it to create a dictionary. My find function inside the tree works as it should, however, when I try and call it inside of my dictionary class, I get a compiler error "expected primary-expression before '>' token." Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong? I'm not very familiar with trying to call functions from other files.

This is my find function from the binary search tree, inside of bst.h

```
    V & find (K key)                      
    {

    TreeNode<K,V> *traverseFind;

    traverseFind = root; 
    unsigned int compareTraverseToHeight = 0;

    while (compareTraverseToHeight < heightCount) 
    {
        if (traverseFind == NULL)  // Fallen off
        {
            keyFinder = 0;
            break;

        }

        else if ( key == traverseFind->key )// Found key
        {
            keyFinder = 1;
            break;
        }       

        else if ( key < traverseFind->key )                   
        {                                                 .
            traverseFind = traverseFind->left;
        }   


        else
        {
            traverseFind = traverseFind->right;
        }  


         compareTraverseToHeight++;      

    }  // end of loop


            if(keyFinder ==0)
            {
                throw key_not_found_exception();

            }


        cout<<"RETURNED "<<traverseFind->value<<endl;

        return traverseFind->value;

}
```

And the dictionary:

```
    #include bst.h

    template <class K, class V> class Dictionary
    {
    public:

        BinarySearchTree<K,V> wiktionary;

        Dictionary()
        {
        }

        ~Dictionary()
        {
        }

    V & find (K key)
    {

        return(wiktionary.find(<V>));  //this is the issue

    }



    private:


    };

    #endif
```

And the application in main:

```
int main()
{

    Dictionary<string, int> d;
    int val = d.find("abc");
    if (val != 15)
        throw dictionary_tester_exception(__FILE__, __LINE__);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Use `wiktionary.find(key)` :/

Comment: Oh wow, don't know how I didn't catch that. Make this an answer and I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `<V>` specifies a template argument but you are attempting to pass it to `BinarySearchTree::find()` as function argument instead. The `find` member function isn't templated so even if you attempted to pass it as a template argument that wouldn't work either. Based on the supplied code you should be passing `key` as the argument to `find` like so

```
return(wiktionary.find(key));
```